# I made a score counter but it is late

Tags: lua, coronasdk

```
  function score( e )
    local score_txt = display.newText( e.count, 980, 60, Ariel , 43 )
    timer.performWithDelay( 10, function() score_txt:removeSelf() end)
  end
  Counter = timer.performWithDelay( 10, score, 0 )
```

it is not realy 1/100 second- I checked it. if it is on seconds it is good but when it is les the a seconed it is late/ why is that?

the problem is that the timer delays. for exsample: when its gets to 10000 is means 100 secodns but i Measured time and 127 seconds have passed. the timer in the corona is Inaccurate?

Comment: Actually in lua the timer is - The delay in milliseconds, for example, 1000 = 1 second

Comment: @KumarKS 1/100 of a second is __10__ ms, which is what OP is using in the code.

Comment: i know that. the problem is that the timer delays. for exsample: when its gets to 10000 is means 100 secodns but i Measured time and 127 seconds have passed. the timer in the corona is Inaccurate?

Comment: ok i anderstand thanks to "CoronaSDK - Implementing game timer counting miliseconds" but how do i know if the game is running at 30 or 60 fps?

Comment: The default frame rate is 30 frames per second. Unless you specified it otherwise in your config settings.